# Light from camera flash , Light in Cone Particles and Their Movement

Tags: particle-physics, visible-light

Tonight I was trying to capture the clouds that obscure the stars in a rather stormy desert, so I tried using the flash of my camera to make the surroundings brighter until I noticed my camera was capturing some noise like moving lines that it had not been capturing before I turned on the flash and then I noticed that many small particles were spinning very tidily just like a whirlwind in the cone of my flash light.

What are these particles exactly? The internet suggests they are microscopic moths or (very trivially) dust, but when I moved my hand near the flash a new lower range whirlwind like cone of them would appear near the flash while I can't see anything behind my hand in the areas that are also brightened by the flash. Also, if they are simply dust why would they be spinning very tidily in orderly circular motion around the light cone? Does the light absorb them?! Also the brighter the flash is and the harder the wind blows, I can see more of them and the faster they spin and if I turn off the light and back on after a while, there is few of them and they gradually accumulate to a fixed amount unless another hard wind blows.

Edit: One thing I forgot to mention, I tried blowing them away and it had no effect.

Comment: it sounds like an effect of your flash light. Try another type of light? If they cannot be blown away they are not dust, but a light interference image on the dust?

Comment: @annav Thanks for reaching out. I will try it out tonight but I doubt tonight would be as windy and stormy.

Comment: @annav Sorry, I couldn't reproduce the same results; maybe it was just dust.

Comment: I was also thinking it could be an interference in the liquid of the eye. I have attributed halos seen around some kind of street lights to this. found this https://www.quora.com/Is-it-normal-to-see-halos-around-streetlamps

Comment: @annav You mean it could have been the halos of the dust in the air?

Comment: the reflection from the dust. you would need to do an experiment. Can you not throw dust and try to see it (corn flour for example on a rug that you shake like cleaning a rug). and shine on  the dust?

Comment: @annav I'm out of the environment that it happened to me, but I'll do the experiment you instructed as soon as I get the time. I'm pretty preoccupied lately.

Comment: not to worry. it is just a puzzle.:)

Comment: @annav :) Thanks for helping.